Using cmd to run IDLE
I an unable to run Python IDLE using command prompt on windows 10 OS.
C:\Windows\System32>IDLE
'IDLE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32>IDLE (Python 3.10.6 64-bit)
'IDLE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Re-installed it as well. It does not seem to work.
What would be the possible ways to open it in interactive or script mode without GUI?
Any suggestions?

Go to your python installation and type
dir /s idle.*

Check for an executable - idle.bat or idle.cmd or idle.exe.  In my case, it listed idle.bat in c:\ProgramData\Python\310\Lib\idlelib
Add this to your path in environment variables (assume you know how to do that).  Once that has been done, close your cmd prompt and start a new one.
Now type
where idle.bat

In my case it returned
 c:\ProgramData\Python\310\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat

This means that it can find idle and there are no typos in your path.  If you type idle on the cmd line, it should work.  It won't pop up immediately.  The first time round, it could be a 5 to 10s wait.  Once it has "compiled" the files, it should be a lot quicker

Assuming that you installed the py launcher, which core developers strongly recommend, enter py -m idlelib in Command Prompt or PowerShell.  Or find the IDLE entry under Python on the Start menu.
